# which esp32 board should I select for "ESP32-S" in platformio?

Tags: esp32, platformio

I just bought an ESP32-S, which looks like this : https://99tech.com.au/product/esp32-s-ai/, except the one I bought only have the writing "ESP32-S" and the espressif symbol instead of AI thinker symbol.

I have been searching the internet for a week for a specific tutorial for this "board" and found nothing.
what I have found is mostly that there is ESP32, ESP32-S2, ESP32 WROOM, ESP32 WROVER... but which one is my esp32-S? is it the same with esp32 or is it the esp32 wroom or something else? if I am going to program this using platformio, which board should I pick? or does it matter which board?

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you try "NodeMCU 32S"? I saw it on esp32 board list. I used esp32 before and It was working with nodemcu board

Comment: @cbalakus, ok pcb still processing but i will try when it has arrived. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the "Espressif ESP32 Dev Module" it works for me with the Arduino framework. My chip has ESP32-WROOM-32D but it says ESP32-S on the back of the board.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be compatible with the ESP32 WROOM module.

Comment: ok my pcb is still processing but i will try when it has arrived. thanks!